# How to write a getter method so that it returns an rvalue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

If we have this class definition

```
class BusDetails
{
private:
    string m_busName;
public:
    string BusName() const { return m_busName; }
};
```

how could the getter method be changed or used, so that using the return value as an lvalue would give a compiler error?

For example, if I use it like

```
int main(void)
{
    BusDetails bus;

    bus.BusName() = "abc";    // <--- This should give a compiler error
    cout << bus.BusName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get no compiler error, so apparently the assignment works, but the result is not as expected.

**Update**: this behavior is as expected with build-in types (i.e. the compiler gives an error at the above line of code if I have an `int` as a return type instead of `string`).

Comment: Note that it does return an `rvalue`, except because `operator=` on `srd::string` works with an rvalue on the left, you can still assign to it!

Comment: @Yakk, could you please expand your comment into an answer, as I think it really answers my question and helps explain some interesting behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BusName()` was declared as a const function. So it can't change members.
Your function should return `string&` and not be const.

```
string& BusName() { return m_busName; }
```

In addition you can add for const object (`this` is const):

```
const string& BusName() const { return m_busName; }
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want to change the member, I only want to read it. The second line does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Mihai If you don't want to change the value why your example says `bus.BusName() = "abc";` ?!

Comment: Because I don't want this kind of expression to NOT give any compiler errors. On the surface it looks like it's doing the intuitive thing, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Mihai OH! xD yea the edit with the comment cleared it. Call me stupid but it wasn't easy to spot before.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what behavior you want.

- If you want the assignment to be an error, and keep all of the
  flexibility of value return (e.g. you can modify the code to
  return a calculated value), you can return `std::string const`.
  (This will inhibit move semantics, but that's generally not
  a big issue.)
- If you want to be able to modify the "member", but still want
  to retain flexibility with regards to how it is implemented in
  the class, then you should provide a setter method.  One
  convention (not the only one) is to provide a getter function
  like you have now (but returning `std::string const`), and
  provide a function with the same name `void
  BusName( std::string const& newValue )` to set the value.
  (Other conventions would use a name like `SetBusName`, or return
  the old value, so client code could save and restore it, or
  return `*this`, so client code could chain the operations:
  `obj.BusName( "toto" ).SomethingElse( /*...*/ )`.
- You may also provide a non-const member returning a reference
  to a non-const.  If you do this, however, you might as well make
  the data member public.
- Finally, you might provide a non-const member which returns
  some sort of proxy class, so that assigning to it would in fact
  call a setter function, and converting it to `std::string` would
  call the getter.  This is by far the most flexible, *if* you
  want to support modifications by the client, but it's also by
  far the most complex, so you might not want to use it unless you
  need to.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is kind of expected behavior what you have written.

You do return a copy of `m_busName`. Because you do not return the reference. Therefore a temporary copy of the return variable is made, and then the assignment takes place. `operator=` is `"abc"` called on that copy.

So the way to go would be `string& BusName() const { return m_busName; }`. But that shall give a compiler error.

You kind of want contradictory things. You say `string BusName() const`, yet you want to return a reference that will allow the state of the object to be changed.

However if you don't promise the object will not change you can drop the `const` and go with

```
string& BusName() { return m_busName; };
```

Or if you want to keep the `const`

```
const string& BusName() const { return m_busName; };
```

however this should give an error on the assignment, naturally.

The same goes for functions. If you do pass argument by reference it is a reference. If you see that you modify a copy, you must have not passed it by reference but by value.

Comment: I just didn't see the meaning in returning an lvalue which you can't use, namely bus.BusName(). As it currently stands, you can use it as an lvalue to assign something to it, but you can't use it afterwards. Or maybe only something like "string busName = bus.BusName() = "abc" ", which makes no sense to me. Anyway, the const string& return values does the trick.

Comment: Yea, but the way it is, is consistent, at least to me. It would be strange, to my liking (again), if the function call would get implicitly changed to return a reference. Also you could use the return value `string& busName = bus.BusName(); busName = "abc"; cout << busName`. This way you work on a copy.

Answer (score 1):

The function does return an rvalue.

The problem is that `std::string::operator=` *works* with an rvalue on the left.  Prior to C++11 it was difficult or impossible to prevent it from working: in C++11 they added (relatively late) what is colloquially known as rvalue references to `this`: the ability to overload methods and in-class operators based on the rvalue state of the object.

However, `std::string` was not modified, probably do to a mixture of not much time and dislike of breaking existing code without good reason.

You could patch around this problem a few ways.  You could write your own string class that obeys rvalue reference to `this`.  You could descend from `std::string` and block the `operator=` specifically.    You could write an accessor object that has-a `std::string` that can cast-to `std::string&&` a d `std::string&` (based on rvalue status of `this`) implicitly, but blocks assignment with `delete`d method.

All three have issues.  The last has the fewest issues, the second the most hidden pitfalls, the first is just drudgery.